# Passing a class's "self" to a function outside it such that the class's variables are accessible and modifiable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

Can I pass the `self` instance variable of the class from within the class to some helper function outside the class? For example, will the following work when an object of SomeClass is initialized? Isn't there any type casting required? Is this coding style reliable? Is there any possibility of this feature being dropped off in future releases of Python 2.x?

```
class SomeClass():
    var1 = 7
    def __init__(self):
        some_func(self) # passing self instead of self.var1

def some_func(instance):
    instance.var1 += 1

x = SomeClass()
print x.var1
```

I have `some_func` as a common helper function across many classes that undergo the same transformation, and the `var1` in my current application is a huge dataFrame which I cannot afford to pass a copy of it to the function due to memory constraints. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: `self` is a reference to the instance, so I don't see what makes this special

Comment: Why don't you run it?
Also this won't modify the class variable `SomeClass.var1` it will still remain 7.

Comment: That's how methods are actually called. To a first approximation, `foo = Foo(); foo.bar()` is equivalent `foo = Foo(); Foo.bar(foo)`. That's why all methods take a first argument (conventionally) named `foo` without seemingly having to provide a value when you call it.

Comment: `self` is just another variable. Do with it what you want.

Comment: I ran and it works. And it does modify the class variable SomeClass.var1 for that object instance. Could you please help me with the rest of the question that I just updated?

Comment: "And it does modify the class variable SomeClass.var1 for that object instance. " Not quite. It creates a new instance attribute `.var1` which shadows the class attribute `SomeClass.var1`.

Comment: When I print self.var1 from within the class in the __init__() after calling some_func(), it does print the changed/incremented value.

Comment: There is 0 chance that this would be dropped in a future release of  **Python 2** since there will be absolutely no new feature releases to Python 2. In addition this continues to work in Python **3.6**, **3.7** and beyond. (BTW, have you considered migrating to Python 3)

Comment: @PM2Ring Can you be clear on what you meant by your previous comment?

Comment: Class attributes like `SomeClass.var1` are shared by all instances of a class, so if you modify that class attribute (via the `SomeClass.var1` name) the new value will be seen by all instances when you access `self.var1`. However, if you assign to `self.var1` it doesn't modify `SomeClass.var1`, instead it creates an instance attribute that only belongs to that instance.

Comment: (cont) If you subsequently do `del self.var1` (with the `self` of that instance) then you'll again be able to access `SomeClass.var1` using `self.var1`. Of course, you can always access (or modify) the class attribute via the class name, i.e., `SomeClass.var1`, even when you've shadowed it with an instance attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would have been to try it out :)
yes, it works, as you expect

```
class SomeClass():
    var1 = 7
    def __init__(self):
        some_func(self) # passing self instead of self.var1

def some_func(instance):
    instance.var1 += 1

x = SomeClass()
print x.var1
```

But in most cases it would be better to make some_func to a member of SomeClass

Comment: That's one of the things I like best about Python: most things work as you expect.

Comment: I have some_func as a common helper function across many classes that undergo the same transformation, and the var1 in my current application is a huge dataFrame which I cannot afford to send to it as a copy due to memory constraints. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could make it a method of a mix-in class that the other classes inherit from, but that's probably  overengineering. There is nothing wrong with having a plain function that takes arbitrary instances as arguments.

Comment: Can I be *safe* assuming this kind of working remains supported in the future releases of Python 2.x?

Comment: @VineethBhaskara: This functionality is a fundamental part of how Python works, it won't change. However, there will not be a Python 2.8, and you are not safe to build new software in Python 2, since that will not be supported after 2020.